# How do I troubleshoot a PDO object that isn't working and doesn't give an error?

Tags: php, class, object, pdo

Stuck again with object/classes. I have a function called submitticket which will submit a new  row into my ticket table.

```
public function submitticket() {
    $correct = false;
    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (ticketid, EPMSAccount, requester, recipient, jobnumber, subject, body, responseid, type, priority) VALUES (:ticketid, :EPMSAccount, :requester, :recipient, :jobnumber, :subject, :body, :responseid, :type, :priority)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        //print_r($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue( "ticketid", $this->ticketid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "EPMSAccount", $this->EPMSAccount, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "requester", $this->requester, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "recipient", $this->recipient, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "jobnumber", $this->jobnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "subject", $this->subject, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "body", $this->body, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "responseid", $this->responseid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "type", $this->type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "priority", $this->priority, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($stmt);
        echo '</pre>';
        $stmt->execute();


        return "Ticket created!";

    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This is how I'm executing it in my code:

```
// Submit ticket if submit clicked
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit Ticket'){
    $_POST['requester'] = $_SESSION['name'];
    $_POST['EPMSAccount'] = $_SESSION['EPMSAccount'];
    $tkt = new Ticket; // New instance of ticket class
    $tkt->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    $tkt->storeFormValues( $_SESSION );
    $tkt->submitticket();
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($tkt);
    print_r ($stmt);
    echo '</pre>';

} else {
echo 'nothing attempted';
}
```

I know this query should be correct, but its not writing anything to my table. Here is what the var_dump and print_r is giving me:

```
PDOStatement Object
(
[queryString] => INSERT INTO tickets (ticketid, EPMSAccount, requester, recipient, jobnumber, subject, body, responseid, type, priority) VALUES (:ticketid, :EPMSAccount, :requester, :recipient, :jobnumber, :subject, :body, :responseid, :type, :priority)
)
object(Ticket)#2 (12) {
["ticketid"]=>
NULL
["EPMSAccount"]=>
string(7) "SHAWMUT"
["jobnumber"]=>
string(6) "123456"
["estnumber"]=>
NULL
["requester"]=>
string(14) "Gabriel Peluso"
["recipient"]=>
string(16) "Customer Service"
["subject"]=>
string(4) "2323"
["body"]=>
string(5) "23232"
["order"]=>
NULL
["responseid"]=>
NULL
["type"]=>
NULL
["priority"]=>
string(6) "Normal"
}
```

I can't figure out how to see the actual SQL query with the binded PDO values. Is it possible to product that? Any way I can find out why its not writing to the table?

Comment: I don't think you can see the actual query.

Comment: How would you go about finding what's wrong? It's not even giving me any type of error

Comment: it is actually giving but you don't seem to reading it

Answer (score 1):

Check that `$stmt` is not `false` when set, also that `$stmt->execute();` does not return `false`.

If they do then use the `errorInfo()` method available for both PDO connections and statements to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually doing anything with the return value (the success message or the exception message).

To see what is happening, you could change:

```
$tkt->submitticket();
```

to:

```
echo $tkt->submitticket();
```

Apart from that, `$stmt` is a local variable in your function, so if you want to see its contents, you need to `var_dump` it in the function itself.